# MySQL read parameter from file for select statement

Tags: mysql

I have a select query as follows:

```
select * from abc where id IN ($list);
```

The problem with the length of variable `$list`, it may have a length of 4000-5000 characters, as a result of which the length of actually executed query increases and its get pretty slow.

Is there a method to store the values of `$list` in a file and ask MySQL to read it from that file, similar to `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name'` for insertion into table?

Comment: Do you have an index on column `id` ?

Comment: Yes but the issue is the resultant query is very large in length, reading that parameter form file would be great if possible

Comment: The query size should not matter so much, this is why I asked. I will post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can (TM)!

- First step: Use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (id ... PRIMARY KEY)` and `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` to create and fill a temporary table holding your value list
- Second step: Run `SELECT abc.id FROM abc INNER JOIN temp ON abc.id=temp.id`

I have the strong impression this only checks out as a win, if you use the same value list quite a few times.